# Group video chat / conference call?

Tags: webapp-rec

Skype does not allow video chat between more than two participants.

Is there a **video** chat / conference call service that allows more than two participants to share video?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest service I have found for this: http://tinychat.com/

Supports MANY more than 3 video users. Nothing to install (but flash). Cheers!

Comment: This service has changed its look quite a bit from its initial launch, but don't let the "light" and "happy" colors discourage you from trying this quality product. :) (It's free, afterall.)

Answer (score 1):

If you and the other participants are on Windows, there's a [beta version of Skype](http://blogs.skype.com/garage/2010/05/skype_50_beta_1_for_windows.html) which allows up to 5-way group video calls.

If you're all on Mac, [iChat](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2515) supports multiperson calls.

---

Update: The beta allowing for group calls is also [available for Mac](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/macosx/beta/).